# Un-ticking message not persistent in Gnus

Tags: emacs, email-client, gnus, maildir

I'm using Gnus with offlineimap to connect to an IMAP server.
I'm having issues with the tick mark ("!").  I can mark messages o.k. and when I come back they're still marked.  The problem is, when I try to "untick" them (via the "@" key) they still come back marked when I come back to the group on a restart.  Interestingly:

1. If I quit (using "q") from the inbox group and re-enter it, the messages are still unticked.
2. If I quit from the group and then from Gnus (using "q" twice), when I restart the messages are ticked again!

I wouldn't think this should have anything to do with offlineimap because I get the same behaviour even if it isn't running.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  (I'm a newbie to Gnus, for whatever it's worth!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By hitting '@' you are toggling the mark for the gnus-agent, indicating you want to download the article. Based on the setup you describe, this is not what you want to do.
You can use 'd' *mark-as-read* to indicate that the article is read.
Reading the section **Marking Articles** in the **Summary Buffer** section of the gnus info pages may help clarify.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey!  That is certainly not what I want to do, and I like hitting 'd' better than C-M-k.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like marking them read (C-M-k) does what I wanted it to do.  I'll have to read up on the difference between the two commands.